# What's the difference between an [[alloc]init] and a [[thing]retain]?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I was wondering, what (if any) is the difference between creating objects using:

```
NSThing *thing = [[NSThing alloc] initWithObject:object];
```

vs

```
NSThing *thing = [[NSThing thingWithObject:object] retain];
```

Is there a difference in how the memory management works? Also, when is it common practice to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allocating and initialising an object is *slightly* more efficient, because `thingWithObject:` will do an `alloc`, then `init`, then `autorelease` which you counter with a `retain`, so you add something to the autorelease pool. The first option only involves an `alloc` and a `init`.

Personally, I use the explicit `alloc` when I want to be clear that the object's lifetime will be handled by me, and I use the convenience methods (`thingWithThing:`) for any object that I won't need outside of the scope it is created in.

For example, explicitly allocating and initialising within a loop is generally preferred, so that you don't flood the autorelease pool. I also use an explicit `alloc`+`init` rather than `thingWithThing:` + `retain` for objects that need to survive an iteration of the run loop.